# outputting an array with overlapping fields

Tags: arrays, powershell

Good afternoon,
I am having a little trouble outputting a powershell custom object.

Its an array showing people and what fruit they have (the information is collected through a number of other processes and would be a real PITA to change) eg;

```
First, last,<fruit>
Joe, Bloggs, apple=$true, banana=$true, pear=$true
Fred, Smith, apple=$true, melon=$true, banana=$true
Mick, Jones, pear=$true, melon=$true
```

If I use
    $array | fl *
everything looks fine:

```
First: Joe
Last: Bloggs
apple: True
Banana: True
Pear: True

First: Mick
Last: Jones
apple: True
melon: True
banana: True

First: Fred
Last: Smith
Pear: True
melon: True
```

unfortunately when using out-gridview or export-csv or $array|ft * for that matter it only shows fields which are common across all records eg

```
$array|ft *
First     Last
----      ----
Joe       Bloggs
Mick      Jones
Fred      Smith
```

What I would like it do to is show all the combinations but just miss out the ones that don't exist,

```
$array|ft *
First     Last     Apple     Banana     Pear     Melon
----      ----     ----      ----       ----     ----
Joe       Bloggs   True      True       True
Mick      Jones    True      True                True
Fred      Smith                         True     True
```

*(The easiest way would just be to join each fruit on to a Fruit" key/value for each record/person like*

```
First: Joe
Last: Bloggs
Fruit: {apple, banana, melon}
```

*"but that wouldn't work quite so well for the end goal)*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format-Table uses the first element's property list, so you'll need to manually build the list of all properties that exist in the array:

```
$fruits = $array | ForEach { $_.PSObject.Properties.Name -ne 'First' -ne 'Last' } |
                   Sort -unique
$properties = @('First', 'Last') + $fruits
$array | ft $properties
```

(The above code is for PS3.0+, so in PS2.0 use `($_.PSObject.Properties | Select -expand Name)` instead of `$_.PSObject.Properties.Name`)

**Or fix the first element** so that Format-Table / Export-Csv / ConvertTo-Csv work correctly as is:

```
$missing = @{}
$array | ForEach { $_.PSObject.Properties | Select -expand Name } |
         Sort -Unique |
         Where { $array[0].$_ -eq $null } |
         ForEach { $missing.$_ = $null }
$array[0] | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $missing
```

Now the cmdlets will output all properties:

- `$array | ft`

  > ```
  > First Last   apple Banana Pear melon
  > ----- ----   ----- ------ ---- -----
  > Joe   Bloggs  True   True True      
  > Mick  Jones   True   True      True 
  > Fred  Smith               True True
  > ```
- `$array | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation`

  > ```
  > "First","Last","apple","Banana","Pear","melon"
  > "Joe","Bloggs","True","True","True",
  > "Mick","Jones","True","True",,"True"
  > "Fred","Smith",,,"True","True"
  > ```